# Vagrant server not showing up?

Tags: php, mysql, apache, curl, vagrant

I'm using Vagrant to run a server for me. So I followed [this](http://www.dev-metal.com/setup-basic-lamp-stack-linux-apache-mysql-php-ubuntu-12-04/) tutorial and when I open up my browser to go check. I get `Oops! Google Chrome could not connect to 127.0.0.1`. I've also tried `localhost` and my IP address. Along with a mixture of different ports. The odd part is when I do
 `curl 'localhost'` or `curl 'http://127.0.0.1:80'` I get

```
<html><body><h1>It works!</h1>
<p>This is the default web page for this server.</p>
<p>The web server software is running but no content has been added, yet.</p>
</body></html>
```

I do know that's normal, but I can only get that to show on the command line. Any ideas?

Comment: Is this when you curl from your local machine or from the vagrant box?

Comment: From my vagrant box. When I try it in my local machine I get `curl: (7) Failed connect to 127.0.0.1:80; Connection refused` @CameronMartin

Comment: See the answer I posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must set up port forwarding in your Vagrantfile. See https://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/networking/forwarded_ports.html

**Example:**

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 80, host: 8080
end
```

Comment: Well I already see this in my file. `# Create a forwarded port mapping which allows access to a specific port
  # within the machine from a port on the host machine. In the example below,
  # accessing "localhost:8080" will access port 80 on the guest machine.
  # config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 80, host: 8080` Do I uncomment something?

Comment: So now I have this `config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 80, host: 8080` and I've tried curl and checking in my browser but everything is the same. Curl on vagrant box still works fine

Comment: Have you ran `vagrant reload` to reload the configuration file?

Comment: I just turned it off and started it back up. But didn't work `vagrant reload` worked. Thanks alot!

Answer (score 0):

I've had issues using Vagrant and got some help.
Here is my post and how i made it work:

[Setting up Vagrant with PuPHET failure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21506936/setting-up-vagrant-with-puphet-failure)